# Getting user info without authenticating App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

We can get user profile info after user can authenticates out app.

Is there any way/possible so that we can get any fb profile info without authenticating? like when user click's on login button.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't retrieve a user's data without them authorising your app to do so using one of the [Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) methods.

If you ever find a way to get a user's data without their consent you should report it via Facebook's [Whitehat security program](https://www.facebook.com/whitehat), possibly for a cash bounty

Comment: You can fetch his public info via Graph api though, provided you have his username or userid

Comment: And how would you get someone's user ID without their authorising your app? there's a limited amount of public data available through the API, but there should be no way to obtain the Facebook user ID of someone visiting your site without them granting permission to your app